# custom CM docker image crashes

Tags: docker

I am currently running through the guides on https://containers.doc.sitecore.com/docs/ to get more comfortable with the ecosystem that Sitecore provides to run Sitecore 10 on docker. When working on the example "[Apply config transformations](https://containers.doc.sitecore.com/docs/config-transforms)", things go wrong. It looks like that the CM image isn't working correctly.

After running

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.xm1.yml -f docker-compose.xm1.override.yml build solution cm cd
```

i didn't get any errors, nor when running

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.xm1.yml -f docker-compose.xm1.override.yml up -d
```

But, when I try to access the cm instance, treafik shows the following error:

> 404 page not found

After checking the running containers, i wasn't able to find the cm-image. Checking the logs for that container, learned me the following:

> Stopping service 'w3svc'
>
> Service 'w3svc' has been stopped
>
> APPCMD failed with error code -1072894421
>
> Failed to update IIS configuration
> [2020-08-07T11:55:01.000Z][LOGMONITOR] INFO: Entrypoint processs exit code: -2147467259

anyone who knows how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I didn't find the *rootcause*, i was able to fix the issue. I first stopped the containers using

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.xm1.yml -f docker-compose.xm1.override.yml down
```

after this shutdown, I cleaned the docker directory using the provided clean.ps1 script in the "custom-images/docker" directory, which wipes the data and deploy directories.

After this step, I did a re-init on the .env file and changed the hostname to something different. After running

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.xm1.yml -f docker-compose.xm1.override.yml up -d
```

the image came up correctly and traefik was able to route me to cm instance.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I did not need to change the hostname; just the stop/clean/reinit was enough.